# jTweetsAnywhere tweetFilters and searchParams

Tags: javascript, twitter, filter

I'm using the jTweetsAnywhere plugin and I was confused about the tweet filters.

My goal is to retrieve ONLY tweets that were created by me, and ONLY tweets containing a specific hashtag... Here's the code I have currently...

```
$('#TWEETS').jTweetsAnywhere({
    username: 'myName',
    count: 10,
    searchParams: ['q=#myhashtag'],
```

For some reason, I can't use the "username" and "searchParams" together... I was wondering if someone could help me make a tweetFilter.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the username or the searchParams option as the source for a tweet feed. If searchParams is set username is ignored.

This should work without the need of coding a tweetFilter.

```
$('#TWEETS').jTweetsAnywhere({
    count: 10,
    searchParams: ['q=%23myhashtag from:myName']
});
```

Hint: If you want to search for a hashtag use %23 instead of #, if you want to search for tweets that just contain the text myhashtag omit %23